# AngularJS anonymous function as argument in interpolation

Tags: angularjs

In my controller I have a function that takes another function as an argument, something like:

```
$scope.myFun = (values, selector) => {
    values.forEach((value) => {
        selector(value);
    }
}
```

Can I call this from my HTML using interpolation? I've tried:

```
{{ myFun(myVar, function(var) {return var/2;}) }}
```

unfortunatelly to no success, the syntax in the interpolation is not valid.

Comment: It might help if you say what you're trying to attempt to do as it doesn't make much sense at the moment. Why are you trying to call a function with a callback?

Comment: You can't declare functions or create regular expressions from within AngularJS expressions. This is to avoid complex model transformation logic inside templates. Such logic is better placed in a controller or in a dedicated filter where it can be tested properly. See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Expressions - function declaration](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#no-function-declarations-or-regexp-creation-with-literal-notation)

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be simply reorganized to the following:

```
$scope.myFun = (values) => {
    values.forEach((value) => {
        value = value / 2;
    }
}
```

And you should think this way - do not spread application logic through the all layers, better keep it one place - in controller or, better, in service. This way it can be covered with tests and much easier for another developer, or sometimes even you, to understand what's going on in the code.

Use templates just to interact with user and avoid putting additional complexity into html files.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not valid in angularJs. Based on your .forEach, you are looping through items and executing a function. This could be ok on the controller if you fixed a few issues, but not directly from template. The calculation function (item/2) itself has to be somewhere in angularjs, like your controller or a service.

Also, you are not returning anything from your calculation, so even if you did fix the above, you still need to return the result.

Refactor as such:

```
<div ng-repeat="val in [2,4,6]">
    {{ $ctrl.myFun2(val, $ctrl.calc ) }}  
</div>
```

And on controller (es6)

```
  myFun2(value, selector) {
    return selector(value);
  }

  calc(val) {
    return val / 2;
  }
```